How to connect to mariadb 10.3.39 via ssh tunneling from C# mysql client?
I am using Connector/Net 2.1.23 libraries in C# to connect to MariaDB instances, using the built-in ssh tunneling.
The program sets up the connection to my MariaDB 5.5.68 instance on server S1 like so:
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.UserID = "db-user-id";
builder.Password =  "db-user-pwd";
builder.Server = "localhost";
builder.SshHostName = "ip-addr-of-S1";
builder.SshUserName = "userid-on-db-server";
builder.SshPassword = "user-pwd-on-db-server";
builder.Database = "my_db_name";
var _my_connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

if (_my_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    _my_connection.Open();


This works fine.  However, if I then repoint the same program to a new machine S2 running MariaDB 10.3.39, I get failures like so:
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: An established connection was aborted by the server.
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at MySql.Data.Common.MySqlSshClientManager.SetupSshClient(String sshHostName, String sshUserName, String sshPassword, String sshKeyFile, String sshPassphrase, UInt32 sshPort, String server, UInt32 port, Boolean isXProtocol)
   at MySql.Data.Common.Ssh.StartClient()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()


I am able to connect using HeidiSQL from local machine to either S1 or S2.  S2 is running RedHat 8.4.
Final note:  Connector/Net 2.1.24 onward has dropped SSH tunneling feature altogether!
Per above, I verified that I can connect from 3rd-party mysql client like HeidiSQL.
I also found that I can actually get in from command line:
c:\users\me>  ssh -l userid-on-db-server -L 3306:localhost:3307 ip-addr-of-S2
[enter pwd]
userid-on-db-server$  
userid-on-db-server$  mysql -u db-user-id -p
[enter pwd]
MariaDB [(none)]> ...


So I'm not really sure what the actual problem is.

If you're using ssh -L 3306:localhost:3307 then that means that the DB is listening on port 3307 on the remote server. So you might need to add builder.SshPort = 3307; to your code.
OTOH, if you're running this program twice on the same computer, both instances of the program might be trying to port-forward by binding to the local port 3306, which won't work. You would need to use unique local ports.

You could also try adapting this code, which can work with MySql.Data or MySqlConnector: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/connect-ssh/
